# Coordinate descent for quadratic cost with $1$-norm regularization and box constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Coordinate descent is a powerful method for solving optimization problems like

$$\min_x \tfrac{1}{2}x^T A x + b^T x + \lambda \|x\|_1$$

where $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, $\lambda>0$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the 1-norm on ${\bf R}^n$.

Say that I want to solve a version of the problem with constraints, for example coordinate-wise inequality constraints

$$l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i$$

or equality constraints

$$x_i = c_i$$

for some or all coordinates. In principle these could be general linear equality or inequality constraints, but I'd be happy with coordinate-wise constraints.

For unconstrained coordinate descent there is a simple algorithm

```
while not converged:
    for i = 1:n
        set x(i) to the value that minimizes the obj function, holding
        other coordinates fixed.
```

What is the corresponding algorithm with coordinate-wise equality or inequality constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coordinate-wise equality constraints are trivial. Just fix $x_i=c_i$ and skip that coordinate during the search. More complex equality constraints are likely not possible here. After all, it's unlikely that you will be able to hold *all* of the other coordinates fixed and maintain feasibility.

Coordinate-wise bounds are not difficult to deal with, either. When you are working with coordinate $i$, you simply have to respect those corresponding inequality constraints. So you can descend in an unconstrained fashion, but stop if the descent direction takes you outside of the interval $[l_i,u_i]$.

If, at a given iteration, you find that you cannot take a step in a descent direction without violating the constraint, then you don't: $x_i$ remains fixed, and you move to the next coordinate. So for instance, suppose $x_i\neq 0$; then the partial derivative is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = x^TAe_i + b^Te_i + \lambda \mathop{\textrm{sign}}(x_i)$$
If $x_i=l_i$ and this quantitiy is positive, *or* if $x_i=u_i$ and this quantity is negative, then the value of $x_i$ will not change in this iteration. If $x_i=0$, of course, then you have a subgradient to deal with, but the point is the same.

More complex linear inequality constraints should be possible to handle as long as they define a polyhedron with a non-empty interior (so, e.g., there cannot be "opposing" inequalities creating an effective equality constraint.) Consider constraints $Fx\leq g$, and suppose that the current point $x$ is feasible (that is, $Fx\leq g$), and we're scheduled to move coordinate $i$. Then we seek $[t_\min,t_\max]$ as follows:
$$t_\min=\inf\{t~|~F(x+te_i)\leq g\}, \quad t_\max=\sup\{t~|~F(x+te_i)\leq g\}$$
This can be solved analytically; and because $Fx\leq g$, know that $t_\min\leq 0$ and $t_\max\geq 0$. Then we can define
$$l_i = x_i + t_\min, \quad u_i = x_i + t_\max$$
and proceed with a coordinate descent constrained to the interval $[l_i,u_i]$, just as we did above.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Michael. Is it easy to see that when dealing with coordinate-wise bounds, thresholding to $l_i\leq x_i\leq u_i$ at each step results in the global minimizer for the problem I posed (convex function with separable non-smooth constraints and coordinate-wise bounds)?

Comment: Yes, it is. The convexity of the function and the constraint set give you this. Keep in mind that you could rewrite this problem in a pseudo-unconstrained form:$$\text{minimize}_x ~ \tfrac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx+\lambda\|x\|_1+\mathop{\textrm{box}}_{l,u}(x)$$where the box function is just the indicator function of the constraint set. Any algorithm that purports to converge for the general smooth/non-smooth convex case can support convex constraints with non-empty interiors using a transformation like this.

Comment: By indicator function I mean this:$$\mathop{\textrm{box}}_{l,u}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & l \preceq x \preceq u \\ +\infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$Heck, you even have strong convexity here since $A$ is positive definite, which enhances convergence.